# Find the sum of the convergent series

Tags: calculus

4 + 3 + 9/4 + 27/16....

I know the first n term is 0 and the pattern is something like 3^n but I can't figure out the rest. I know its a geometric series but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Can you figure out what $a$ and $r$ is?